# Freemarker template parser or snakeyaml does not print json strings as expected

Tags: json, templates, yaml, freemarker, snakeyaml

We are trying to print out a json formatted string as a value for in yaml file without quotes. We are using Freemarker template engine version 2.3.26 and dumping the output in yaml files using `org.yaml.snakeyaml` library.

We either see json converted to yaml or json surrounded with single quotes; even though https://try.freemarker.apache.org/ seems to show it is possible.

Following are few examples with code snippet and corresponding output:

```
<#assign a = '{"key": "val"}'>
setting_a: ${a?string}
```

prints (without quotes)

```
string_a:
  key: val
```

```
<#assign a = '{"key": "val"}'>
setting_a: ${a?js_string}
```

prints (with quotes and escaping)

```
setting_a:
  \"key\": \"val\"
```

```
<#assign a = "{"key": "val"}">
setting_a: ${a?json_string}
```

prints (with quotes and escaping)

```
setting_a:
  \"key\": \"val\"
```

```
<#assign a = "{\"key\": \"val\"}">
setting_a: ${a?string}
```

prints (without quotes)

```
setting_a:
    key: val
```

```
<#assign a = "{"key": "val"}">
setting_a: ${a?js_string}
```

prints (with quotes and escaping)

```
setting_a:
  \"key\": \"val\"
```

```
<#assign a = "{"key": "val"}">
setting_a: ${a?json_string}
```

prints (with quotes and escaping

```
setting_a:
  \"key\": \"val\"
```

What we are expecting is output `yaml` file is

setting_a: {"key": "val"}.

- Is this possible?
- If so, do we need to select specific `org.yaml.snakeyaml.DumperOptions` for this?
- If this is not possible, I am wondering if I am choosing incorrect options on https://try.freemarker.apache.org/

Comment: What's the problem with the first output? What output are you expecting instead?

Comment: Also, some of the later examples doesn't look real, as they would be FreeMarker syntax errors, yet you are showing output for them.

Comment: The output we are expecting is: `setting_a: {"key": "val"}.` (without outside quotes around value). We are wondering if it is even possible if we using Freemarker template followed by snakeyaml for dumping the output into yaml and expecting the above string as an output.

Comment: From the output it appears the output is parsed as YAML, and then printed in some canonical form (so it's reformatted). Therefore, the original syntax is lost, but the meaning remains the same. So why do you care? The meaning of the first output is the same as the meaning of `setting_a: {"key": "val"}`.

Comment: Yeah, ideally we should not care (if it is json or yaml, as long as the meaning is not lost). The consumer of the setting expects it to be json. Said that, the more I think about it - this sounds like unreasoable ask - expecting `json` parsed properly inside a yaml file. What do you think?

Comment: The YAML file as a whole has to be valid JSON? JSON is usually valid YAML, but not the other way around, obviously. So if they want JSON, you should just generate JSON instead of YAML. (Also, it's certainly clear at this point, but FreeMarker can't do much about this... its output is parsed and then re-formatted, so it's out f its reach.)

Comment: Thanks for your helpful responses. I concur that this is not an issue with FreeMarker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first example prints `{"key": "val"}` in any version of FreeMarker. So I guess  you are showing the result of parsing the output of the template as YAML. (While https://try.freemarker.apache.org shows the template output as is.) In that case, I think it should be: `setting_a: "${a?js_string}"`.

Also, `<#assign a = "{"key": "val"}">` is syntax error in FreeMarker, and so you shouldn't get any output.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. Yes, I guess it is not clear from the question; but we are using `org.yaml.snakeyaml` library to read the output and dump it into a yaml file. Given this, is it possible to get the desired output using `org.yaml.snakeyaml.DumperOptions`? I have updated the question accordingly